# JS simple math task (raising an inputed number to a power)

Tags: javascript, math

I have a task in js. My program should take a number from a user and put it into power that is also inserted. I have coped with positive powers but the algorithm for negative ones always gives a positive answer and after putting an option for a zero power every variant somehow returns -1; Please help me find an error.

```js
function powX(x, pow) {
  x = +prompt('Insert a number: ');
  pow = +prompt('Insert a power: ');
  var result;
  if (x > 0) {
    var result = x;
    for (i = 1; i < pow; i++) {
      result *= x;
    }
  }
  if (x < 0) {
    var result = x;
    for (i = 1; i < Math.abs(pow); i++) {
      result /= x;
    }
  } else {
    result = 1;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(powX());
```

Comment: You want to check for negative numbers or negative powers?

Comment: Quite a few mistakes 1) misplaced `else` 2) `x><0` should be `pow >< 0`, 3) the start value should be `1`, not `x`, 4) loops should start with 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in the code:

- You should use `else-if` instead of `if` in your second block.
- You should check `pow` instead of `x`
- You are not using `var` or `let` with `i` so it will become global variable. Use `let` or `var`
- You are using `var` again inside your `if` blocks but variables declared with `var` have function scope so it will not throw error. But with `let` it will break your code. Don't redeclare `result` again and again.

```js
function powX(x, pow) {
  x = +prompt('Insert a number: ');
  pow = +prompt('Insert a power: ');
  var result;
  if (pow > 0) {
    result = x;
    for (let i = 1; i < pow; i++) {
      result *= x;
    }
  }
  else if (pow < 0) {
    result = x;
    for (let i = 0; i <= Math.abs(pow); i++) {
      result /= x;
    }
  } else {
    result = 1;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(powX());
```

You don't need two loops one to divide and other using multiply. Just calculate the `result` just by multiplying and at the end multiply the result with `x` or divide it based on condition.

```js
function powX(x, pow) {
  x = +prompt('Insert a number: ');
  pow = +prompt('Insert a power: ');
  if(pow === 0) return 1;
  var result = x;
  for (let i = 1; i < Math.abs(pow); i++) {
    result *= x;
  }
  return pow < 0 ? (x/result/x) : result; 
}

console.log(powX());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `else if` for your second condition, otherwise, its `else` block will always be executed for x > 0, setting your result to 1.

```js
function powX(x, pow) {
  x = +prompt('Insert a number: ');
  pow = +prompt('Insert a power: ');
  var result;
  if (x > 0) {
    result = x;
    for (i = 1; i < pow; i++) {
      result *= x;
    }
  }
  else if (x < 0) {
    result = x;
    for (i = 1; i < Math.abs(pow); i++) {
      result /= x;
    }
  } else {
    result = 1;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(powX());
```

Also, it'll look better if you remove the re-declaration of `result` in the `if` and `else if` blocks. It won't affect your output but still.

*Note: As @ASDFGerte correctly pointed out in the comments, OP's code has other flaws, but I think this still answers his main concern and actual question.*

Comment: While this may be true, the OP's code is broken a lot more than "just" that. E.g. it checks, whether `x` is positive or negative, but not the `pow`.